# How to resolve type name conflict from two separate Javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Let me start by saying that I'm primarily a C# programmer who only extremely rarely ventures into JavaScript.

I can write myself some JS code as long as its mostly plain. I can handle jQuery and the odd self-sufficient 3rd-party library, but couldn't code myself out of a wet paper bag when React, Angular, Bootstrap and others enter the scene. I'm also not used to using npm or any other similar package manager.

It was never really my job nor interest, so I never went there. Whenever I code some JS, I reference the required JS files in my `<script>` tags and then use them as directly as possible.

I'm currently creating a very simple proof of concept web app which will have its client parts rebuilt by competent people sooner or later. But in the mean time I have to provide the bare-bones functionality that will serve as a rough guideline for the next team to take over, whenever that might be.

I've picked two libraries that each seem easy to use and get the job done, when used separately. But when I try to use them together on the same page, I run into a problem: they both use the same name for their main type, and I can't seem to disambiguate between them.

These are the libraries:

- [JSON Editor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor)
- [JSON Schema Form Builder](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor/)

They both declare a type named `JSONEditor`, which I can use as long as I don't reference both of the libraries at once.

So far I've tried to solve this by using modules and `import`-ing the type using different names, but it didn't work... I got a bunch of errors in the console about "import not found" and "e is not defined", which makes me think I'm tackling this wrong.

How would I solve this using plain JS if possible?

**UPDATE**: As suggested, I'm providing a minimal example that demonstrates my use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link href="/lib/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="editor" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="form"></div>
</div>

<!--library 1: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor -->
<script src="/lib/jsoneditor/jsoneditor.min.js"></script>

<!--library 2: https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor -->
<script src="/lib/jsonform/jsonform.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Library 1: The JSON code editor.
    var editor = new JSONEditor(document.getElementById("editor"), { mode: "code" });
   
    // Library 2: The form builder.
    var form = new JSONEditor(document.getElementById("form"), {
        ajax: true,
        schema: {
            $ref: "/api/describe/service/test"
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the use of one library (whichever), the other works as expected and the content is displayed at the respective target `<div>`. But if I try both at once, as shown above, nothing is displayed, and the following error is output to console:

> Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined

This happens at the `var editor = new JSONEditor` line, which makes me think that the type from the second library overwrites the first and causes the problem.

This is understandable to me and isn't the issue per-se. The issue is that I don't know how to import the two `JSONEditor` types so that they can be referenced separately.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you created a small snippet demonstrating how you use the code that results in the clash. There's a button to insert a snippet in the editor next to the image upload button.

Comment: I know this is highly frowned upon, but one simple yet dirty solution is open the js file and simply replace all instances of `JSONEditor` with something else like for the form builder you could rename it to `JSONFormBuilder`.

Comment: @Nit: Good suggestion! I'll try. At worst I'll have something concrete to show you all and at best I'll learn something new myself!

Comment: @imvain2: I might do this as a last resort, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maintainer of the code editor (JSON Editor, not JSON Schema Form Builder) has addressed and closed an issue about exactly this in the past: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/issues/270

His recommended solution is something like the following:

> ```
> <script src="assets/jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>   var JSONEditorA = JSONEditor;
> </script>
> <script src="assets/json-editor/dist/jsoneditor.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>   var JSONEditorB = JSONEditor;
> </script>
> ```

If you must use script tags this is probably the way to go.

Comment: Oh, man! This is brilliant and brain-dead simple, now that I see it! I knew I was right not to venture into JavaScript world. :) Thanks a bunch!